# Graphics doesn't work on a Vostro 1500

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

I could boot the live USB without problem. Using it, I installed 11.10 into an USB Disk. Did the same with previous versions (10.04 and 10.10) without problems before.

Now, when I boot this fresh installation, it shows like a terminal, and the last message is something like "Checking battery state". I can switch to another terminal (tty1) and log in... Already installed nvida-current, gdm, etc... without luck...

Really, I'm very disappointed with 11.10... Its the first version from 9.10 that doesn't work out the box with my Vostro 1500 (nvidia 8600GT Movile)...

Any idea???

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have nvidia proprietary drivers installed , then you need to blaclist nouveau driver.

or try this.

go to the terminal and remove the xorg.conf file using the command:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

see if that helps.